# Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array According to another Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays as follow:

```
var Ids   = ['123',  '456',  '789',   '789'];
var Names = ['jack', 'jack', 'peter', 'peter'];
```

Now I need to remove duplicate values in the `Ids` array and then **according to that**, remove values in the `Names` array.

---

I can remove duplicate values for each array separately using `.filter()` like this:

```
var Unique_Ids   = Ids.filter(function(item, pos) { return Ids.indexOf(item) == pos; });
//=> 123, 456, 789

var Unique_Names = Ids.filter(function(item, pos) { return Names.indexOf(item) == pos; });
//=> jack, peter
```

But that isn't what I need .. I need the number of items in both arrays to be equal *(in this case `3`, according to the number of items in `Unique_Ids`)*.

---

Anyway what I need is this:

```
var Unique_Ids   = ['123',  '456',  '789'];
var Unique_Names = ['jack', 'jack', 'peter'];
```

How can I do that?

---

**Note:** I don't want a solution containing this `indexOf()` method. Because it doesn't work on IE and old browsers. And I think [`jQuery.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) can be a good alternative.

Comment: You mention you don't want to use indexOf, but you're already doing it?
    
     return Names.indexOf(item)

Comment: if you have `array.filter`, you have `array.indexOf`

Comment: @JaromandaX Well I'm trying to find another approach ..

Comment: also `array.indexOf` works in IE9+ - do you really need to support IE8 or earlier?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah .. the most of my website's user use IE7 :-)

Comment: Personally i would tell people with old browsers to go update or they simply can't use your site.. people need to wake up and realise we're in 2016..

Comment: @user2267175 :) .. Seems like rough kinda ..! Well I like to create a user-friendly website ..

Comment: When coming to web designing, IE spoils all the fun :(

Comment: @Munawir Sadly yes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with an temporary object for the ids and a for loop.

```js
function unique(o) {
    var obj = {},
        r = { ids: [], names: [] },
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < o.ids.length; i++) {
        if (!obj[o.ids[i]]) {
            r.ids.push(o.ids[i]);
            r.names.push(o.names[i]);
            obj[o.ids[i]] = true;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

var Ids = ['123', '456', '789', '789'],
    Names = ['jack', 'jack', 'peter', 'peter'],
    result = unique({ ids: Ids, names: Names });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but this will fit your needs:

```
var Ids   = ['123',  '456',  '789',   '789'];
var Names = ['jack', 'jack', 'peter', 'peter'];
var Unique_Ids = [];
var Unique_Names = [];
for(i=0; i<Ids.length; i++) { Unique_Names.push(Names[i]); Unique_Ids.push(Ids[i]); } //Create 2 new arrays without polluting the old ones
var idToCompare;
for(id=0; id<Unique_Ids.length; id++) {
    idToCompare = Unique_Ids[id];
    for(id2=id+1; id2<Unique_Ids.length; id2++) {
        if(Unique_Ids[id] == Unique_Ids[id2]) {
            Unique_Ids.splice(id2, 1);
            Unique_Names.splice(id2, 1);
            id2--;
        }
    }
}
```

First it creates a copy of each of your arrays. This will go through each element of your array `Unique_Ids`, checking if a duplicate and then if so, removing it from both `Unique_Ids` and `Unique_Names`. This will probably be quite slow if done on very large arrays.

As asked for in comments, here is a solution that will change the original arrays:

```
var Ids   = ['123',  '456',  '789',   '789'];
var Names = ['jack', 'jack', 'peter', 'peter'];
var idToCompare;
for(id=0; id<Ids.length; id++) {
    idToCompare = Ids[id];
    for(id2=id+1; id2<Ids.length; id2++) {
        if(Ids[id] == Ids[id2]) {
            Ids.splice(id2, 1);
            Names.splice(id2, 1);
            id2--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he wants new arrays for the output

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the creation of 2 new arrays

Comment: Good .. but please add previous solution again to your solution .. I mean please keep both of them ..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tedious way of doing it

```
var Ids   = ['123',  '456',  '789',   '789'];
var Names = ['jack', 'jack', 'peter', 'peter'];

var i;
var t = {};
var unique_ids = [];
var unique_names = [];

for(i = 0; i < Ids.length; i += 1) {
    var id = Ids[i];
    var name = Names[i];
    t[id] = t[id] || name;
}
for (i in t) {
    if (t.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        unique_ids.push(i);
        unique_names.push(t[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `in` is `in` in `for ... in` - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) ... don't worry, IE7 will handle it, it's been in javascript since June 1997

Comment: Look, this solution is very good .. just for my information, may you please show me how can I do that without new arrays? I mean applying changes on `Ids` and `Names`?

Comment: use the solution that does what you didn't ask in the question, it does exactly what you asked in your comment

Comment: The algorithm of this solution seems correct to me *(using an object)* .. but I don't know why it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/oem9r8kn/

Comment: because, if you look in your browsers developer tools console, you'll see I made a typo ... I **had** `Name[i]` instead of `Names[i]`

Comment: Heh :) .. nice debugging. Ok my last question, If I want do that without new array, do you think is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/oem9r8kn/2/) good or I can improve it?

Answer (score 1):

use this little code :

```
 var Ids   = ['123',  '456',  '789',   '789'];
var Names = ['jack', 'jack', 'peter', 'peter'];
var uniqueIds = [];
var uniqueNames = [];
var i=0;
$.each(Ids, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueIds) === -1) {
        uniqueIds.push(el);
        uniqueNames.push(Names[i]);
        console.log(Names[i]);
        i++;

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the first array and fill new arrays every time a new item is found:

```
var Ids   = ['123',  '456',  '789',   '789'];
var Names = ['jack', 'jack', 'peter', 'peter'];
var Unique_Ids = [];
var Unique_Names = [];
var IndexString='';
for(var i=0;i<Ids.length;i++){
    if(IndexString.indexOf('|'+Ids[i]+'|')==-1){
        Unique_Ids.push(Ids[i]);
        Unique_Names.push(Names[i]);
        IndexString+='|'+Ids[i]+'|'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. But I mentioned: *I don't want a solution containing this `indexOf()` method*

Comment: In case you don't find a better answer,here is an easy fix: http://coding-journal.com/array-indexof-in-internet-explorer-9/

Comment: I also edited to use indexOf on a string instead of an array, which is supported on explorer.